# How can I correctly instantiate tx_news by Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, tx-news

I need to create a instance of tx_news via Typoscript, but when I set startingpoint or limit settings, the plugin is not show in frontend; without these options it dislpays all storage news.

I have followed documentation in https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html#add-news-by-typoscript and other pages. I am using TYPO3 8.7 and PHP 7.1

```
#Remove content in section
page.10.variables.noticiasGNFA > 
lib.news = USER
lib.news {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = News
    pluginName = Pi1
    vendorName = GeorgRinger

    switchableControllerActions {
        News {
            1 = list
            }
    }

    settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
    settings {
        detailPid = 515
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)

        orderBy = datetime
        listPid = 151
        backPid = 151                       
        disableOverrideDemand = true
        templateLayout = 4
        #startingpoint = 318
        #limit =3
    }
}
#Set new tx_news plugin in section 
page.10.variables.noticiasGNFA < lib.news
```

When the comment of any options with hashtag is removed, it does not work. Not display, not show some exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Fluid template, you can use the `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.news"/>` anywhere.

Hope it helps.